# How to provide a list of products in online store via switch? How to use the exit to the main menu? (or another way)

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

Java. There is an online store, classes of products, constructors, etc. (I have all I need) There is also an array of products.
 The switch statement provides a choice, the user need to select the number of product on the console. I want the user to be able to select several products (not only one product), so I added scanners (I hope there is nothing bad in scanner) I have a method which directs user to the main menu, is called in this code as firstMethod (); 
The problem with the transition to the main menu through the switch statement. When I press 1, 3 and so on - the products are displayed, but when I press 6 then firstMethod (the method that calls the main menu in this online store) really work, but not "in time". When I press 1, the 1 case is executed, the program is waiting for my input of the next number. I press 6 (to go to main menu) and for some reason the program displays case 2. Then I press 6 and console displays case 3, and so on. Two more times and the console displays the main menu, this is really what I want to be shown right that moment when I press number 6.
Tell me please - what is wrong with that? How to go to the main menu (call the method) with this operator, or is it better to use another one? Write it please.

So I want firstMethod to work when user press 6 number. Can I do this via switch or I need another operator? Please help I will be really gratefull.

```
public static void switch1() {


    Product[] products = {
            new Fridge(),
            new Fridge(),
            new Fridge(),
```

...
...
...

```
    };

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 - " + products[0]);
    System.out.println("2 - " + products[1]);
    System.out.println("3 - " + products[2]);
    System.out.println("4 - " + products[3]);
    System.out.println("5 - " + products[4]);
    System.out.println("6 - Go to main menu");
    System.out.println("Which one do u want to buy?");
```

int i = Scanner.nextInt();

```
            switch (i) {

                case 1:

                    System.out.println(products[0]);

                   Scanner.nextInt();

                case 2:

                    System.out.println(products[1]);
                   Scanner.nextInt();

                case 3:
                    System.out.println(products[2]);
                   Scanner.nextInt();

                case 4:

                    System.out.println(products[3]);
                  Scanner.nextInt();
                case 5:
                    System.out.println(products[4]);
                  Scanner.nextInt();
                case 6:
                        firstMethod();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only visible problem is that there are no `break;` statements at the end of each of your `case` blocks.

For example:

```
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(products[0]);
        Scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    ...
```

Also, just calling `Scanner.nextInt();` won’t do anything unless you use the value returned by the call.

You also said you wanted the user to be able to select multiple products, so in order to do that, you could put the `switch` in a loop, such as a `while` loop, and have it loop until a condition is met to stop it.

**Edit:** The following code shows a small example of what your code structure could be:

```
boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(product[0]);
            break;
        //... cases 2-5 are similar to case 1
        case 6:
            firstMethod();
            loop = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. It's not a break. break will just stop the program, I tried it. It doesn't work. Thank you anyway

Comment: Well, `break`s are kind of meant to be used with `switch`s. If you use `break`s then only one case will be selected at a time, instead of letting the code fall through any lower cases. What you should do is have your `switch` statement in a method and call it from inside a loop, until some condition is met to stop the loop.

Comment: You didnt understand me. My code is not "falling through any lower cases", when I press the 1 I see product 1, then program waiting for the next number, I press 3 and  program showing product number 3 and waiting for the next number - it IS okay. But when I press 6 (call the method) then I see product 4, then I press 6 one more time and I see 5th, and only after this my method is being called.
You said  only one case will be selected at a time - and that is a problem, I want user to select several cases at the time. And I want user to show main menu if user press 6.

Comment: I understand, what is happening is that when, say case 1 is selected, then you have to go through all the cases before you can select case 6, if that makes sense. If you first pressed 3, then you have to go through all the cases below 3. Because there are no `break`s, whatever case you start at, it has to go through all of the below cases, even if you don't want to. So, the idea I stated before, is that you could have the `switch` called multiple times (perhaps in a loop), until the user makes all his selections.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a much more efficient manner without a switch at all.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + " - " + products[i]);
}
System.out.println((products.length + 1) + " - Go to main menu");
System.out.println("Which one do u want to buy?");

while (true) {
    int selection = Scanner.nextInt();
    if (selection > 0 && selection <= products.length) {
        System.out.println(products[selection - 1]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
firstMethod();
```

Comment: And how can I call the method which directs to main menu? Write it please if its possible. firstMethod is the name.